# How to find a combination of 3 numbers from an array that, when added, equals another given number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array that has multiple numbers in it. I want the function to return another array of maximum 3 numbers from the array that, when added together, equals another number.

It can be 1 or 2 numbers too, but the first number must be the highest possible.

e.g.:

```js
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var number: 25;
```

desired output: [10,10,5]

Or

```js
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var number: 11;
```

desired output: [10,1]

Or

```js
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    var number: 5;
```

desired output: [5]

As you will probably see, i am building a small dart application that calculates your points. this is the last part where i need to show which combination of darts can get you to reach exactly 0 regardless of how many darts i have thrown.

I can loop through my numbers and get them in an array but as soon as the combination needs to have a smaller number before another one, it cant compute. Here's the code:

```js
// the numbers to add
var finishingNumbers = [60, 57, 54, 51, 50, 48, 45, 42, 40, 39, 38, 36, 34, 33, 32, 30, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

// The number
var output = 167;

// The variable for the end result
var dartsToFinishArr = [];

// Call my function
checkArray();

function checkArray() {
    for (var j = 0; j < finishingNumbers.length; j++) {
        var dartsToFinishArrTotal = 0;
        if (dartsToFinishArr.length > 0) {
            for (n = 0; n < dartsToFinishArr.length; n++) {
                dartsToFinishArrTotal += dartsToFinishArr[n];
            }
        }

        if (output <= 180) {
            if (finishingNumbers[j] + dartsToFinishArrTotal == +($(".matchContainer .matchPlayerContainer .player.playerTurn .playerScore .value").text()) && dartsToFinishArr.length < 3) {
                dartsToFinishArr.push(finishingNumbers[j]);
                return;
            } else if (finishingNumbers[j] + dartsToFinishArrTotal < output && dartsToFinishArr.length < 3) {
                dartsToFinishArr.push(finishingNumbers[j]);
                checkArray();

                return;
            } else if (dartsToFinishArrTotal != output) {
            return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this should give me:

```js
    var dartsToFinishArr = [60, 57, 50]
```

but it doesnt

Comment: What have you tried (in words not code)?  Are you sorting the array into ascending or descending order?  If the array is sorted, you should be able to do this by looping in order (or in reverse order) so that you try the largest numbers first.

Answer (score 1):

The logic below goes through all the combinations until it finds three numbers that meet your total.  It also shortcuts to less than three numbers if they meet the total.

```js
// the numbers to add
var finishingNumbers = [60, 57, 54, 51, 50, 48, 45, 42, 40, 39, 38, 36, 34, 33, 32, 30, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

// The number
var output = 167;

console.log( findValues( finishingNumbers, output ) );

function findValues ( numbers, desiredTotal ) {
  numbers = numbers.slice(0).sort((a, b)=>b-a) //sort descending
  
  for ( let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
    if ( numbers[ i ] === desiredTotal ) return [ numbers[ i ] ];
    
    // add in the numbers after the previous number at `i`
    for ( let j = i + i; j < numbers.length; j++ ) {
      if ( numbers[ i ] + numbers[ j ] === desiredTotal ) return [ numbers[ i ], numbers[ j ] ];
      
      // add in the numbers after the previous number at `j`
      for ( let k = j + 1; k < numbers.length; k++ ) {
        if ( numbers[ i ] + numbers[ j ] + numbers[ k ] === desiredTotal ) return [ numbers[ i ], numbers[ j ], numbers[ k ] ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code seems neat! I can't test it inside my program for 2 days but i'm sure it will do the job just fine. I'll let you know if it works for me soon. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**.
I tried to solve it, and I have this code that is working fine.

I have not tried Javascript programming but I have the solution code in C++, so you can check the algorithm:

```
int numbersList[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int targetNumber;

    cout<<"Enter target number: ";
    cin>>targetNumber;

    int a=numbersList[9], b=numbersList[9], c=numbersList[9];

    if (a+b+c==targetNumber)
    {
        cout<<"Answer: a="<<a<<" b="<<b<<" c="<<c<<endl;
    } else {
        int aPos=9, bPos=9, cPos=9;
        for(int i=0 ; i<719 ; i++)
        {
            a = numbersList[aPos];
            b = numbersList[bPos];
            c = numbersList[cPos];
            if (a+b+c==targetNumber)
            {
                cout<<"Possible! a="<<a<<" b="<<b<<" c="<<c<<endl;
                //break;
            } else if (a+b+c>targetNumber)
            {
                if (cPos==0)
                {
                    if (bPos==0)
                    {
                        if (aPos==0)
                        {
                            cout<<"Not possible!"<<endl;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            aPos -=1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        bPos -=1;
                    }
                } else {
                    cPos -=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to check the program, you can try it here -> [Click me](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

And then paste this code:

```
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbersList[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int targetNumber;

    cout<<"Enter target number: ";
    cin>>targetNumber;

    int a=numbersList[9], b=numbersList[9], c=numbersList[9];

    if (a+b+c==targetNumber)
    {
        cout<<"Answer: a="<<a<<" b="<<b<<" c="<<c<<endl;
    } else {
        int aPos=9, bPos=9, cPos=9;
        for(int i=0 ; i<719 ; i++)
        {
            a = numbersList[aPos];
            b = numbersList[bPos];
            c = numbersList[cPos];
            if (a+b+c==targetNumber)
            {
                cout<<"Possible! a="<<a<<" b="<<b<<" c="<<c<<endl;
                //break;
            } else if (a+b+c>targetNumber)
            {
                if (cPos==0)
                {
                    if (bPos==0)
                    {
                        if (aPos==0)
                        {
                            cout<<"Not possible!"<<endl;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            aPos -=1;
                        }
                    } else {
                        bPos -=1;
                    }
                } else {
                    cPos -=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**I hope you got your answer :)**

Comment: If you find any issue with the code, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to solve your problem in javascript:

```
// the numbers to add
var finishingNumbers = [60, 57, 54, 51, 50, 48, 45, 42, 40, 39, 38, 36, 34, 33, 32, 30, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

// The number
var output = 167;

// The variable for the end result
var dartsToFinishArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < finishingNumbers.length; i++) {
  const element1 = finishingNumbers[i];
  if (element1 === output) {
    dartsToFinishArr = [element1];
    return;
  }

  for (let j = 0; j < finishingNumbers.length; j++) {
    const element2 = finishingNumbers[j];
    if (element1 + element2 == output) {
      dartsToFinishArr = [element1, element2];
      return;
    }

    for (let k = 0; k < finishingNumbers.length; k++) {
      const element3 = finishingNumbers[k];
      if (element1 + element2 + element3 === output) {
        dartsToFinishArr = [element1, element2, element3];
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This seems like a fairly typical case of ["how to debug a small program"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and I highly recommend reading the entire blog post, as it will improve your programming skills dramatically.

Now that we have a working solution, let's have some fun! This solution meets your requirement, but you noticed that I have 3 nested for loops. That's not super bad, but if your requirements were to change to have *any* amount of numbers in your solution, my code would quickly explode in a mess of copy and paste. Could we build a solution that takes in the amount of numbers in the solution and always be able to calculate it? You bet! This is a perfect scenario for [recursion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/recursion-in-javascript-1608032c7a1f).

Here is a more complex, but more general solution to your problem:

```
// the numbers to add
var finishingNumbers = [60, 57, 54, 51, 50, 48, 45, 42, 40, 39, 38, 36, 34, 33, 32, 30, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

// The number
var output = 167;

// The variable for the end result
var dartsToFinishArr = [];

// The maximum amount of numbers allowed in the solution;
const maxNumbers = 3;

function sum(total, element) {
  return total + element;
}

function recursiveSolution(possibleSolution) {
  for (let element of finishingNumbers) {

    // Special case when we haven't added anything to the solution yet
    var total = element;
    if (possibleSolution.length > 0) {
      total = possibleSolution.reduce(sum) + element;
    }

    if (total === output) {
      dartsToFinishArr = possibleSolution;
      dartsToFinishArr.push(element);

      //Solution found, return recursively.
      return true;
    }

    if (total < output && possibleSolution.length < maxNumbers - 1) {
      //There's room for more numbers, continue recursively
      const newPossibleSolution = possibleSolution.slice(0);
      newPossibleSolution.push(element);
      if (recursiveSolution(newPossibleSolution)) {
        //The recursion worked, return recursively.
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  //We tried everything with the current possible solution. Let's backtrack one number and try the next one.
  return false;
}

// Start the recursion with an empty solution
recursiveSolution([]);

console.debug(dartsToFinishArr);
```

Now you can modify maxNumbers and you can get any solution you want!

Comment: I can't test until 2 days but the article you linked is very interesting and usefull. I'll let you know if your answer works soon. Thanks a lot internet stranger!

Comment: no problem. I added another solution using recursion for you to study. Good luck!